# How to find associated matrix $[T]_{\alpha}^{\beta}$ for given matrix?

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $$ M=
    \left[\begin{matrix}
    4 & 2 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 3 \\
    \end{matrix}\right]
$$
Find the unique linear transformation $T :\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$
so that $M$ is the associated matrix of $T$ with respect to the bases $\alpha =
\{(1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)\}$ and $\beta=\{(1, 0),(0, 1)\}$

I know how to solve this if the transformation is defined as for example, $(3x+2y-4z, x-5y+3z)$ but how do I solve the problem when I'm directly given a matrix? I just want to know where to start like some steps to start solving.

Comment: The linear transformation is already defined by the matrix. Write a vector in the basis $\alpha$ and multiply on the left by $M$. Presumably the goal is to write an arbitrary vector in the basis $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ in terms of $\alpha$, so that's where you should start.

Answer (score 1):

You are told that$$T(1,0,0)=(4,0)\text{, that }T(1,1,0)=(2,1)\text{, and that }T(1,1,1)=(1,3).$$Therefore\begin{align}T(0,1,0)&=T\bigl((1,1,0)-(1,0,0)\bigr)\\&=(2,1)-(4,0)\\&=(-4,1)\end{align}and\begin{align}T(0,0,1)&=T\bigl((1,1,1)-(1,1,0)\bigr)\\&=(1,3)-(2,1)\\&=(-1,2).\end{align}So,\begin{align}\bigl(\forall(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\bigr):T(x,y,z)&=x(1,3)+y(-4,1)+z(-1,2)\\&=(x-4y-z,3x+y+2z).\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be indicating with $[T]_\alpha^\beta$ the matrix of $T$ with respect to the bases $\alpha$ on the domain and $\beta$ on the codomain. I like it better when it's the other way around, but I'll stick to your notation. I'll also assume that the vectors in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are actually column vectors, otherwise I don't think it makes sense for a $2\times 3$ matrix to represent a map $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$.

Presumably you want $[T]_{\mathcal C'}^{\mathcal C}$, where $\mathcal C'$ and $\mathcal C$ are the canonical bases, therefore you can consider $$[T]_{\mathcal C'}^{\mathcal C}=[id_2\circ T\circ id_3]_{\mathcal C'}^{\mathcal C}=[id_2]_{\beta}^{\mathcal C}[T]^\beta_\alpha [id_3]_{\mathcal C'}^\alpha=[id_2]_{\beta}^{\mathcal C}[T]^\beta_\alpha ([id_3]^{\mathcal C'}_\alpha)^{-1}$$

Now, $[T]^\beta_\alpha$ is given, and $[id_3]^{\mathcal C}_\beta$ is just the matrix having the sequence $\beta$ as columns.